# How to add Javascript methods in MVC view when jquery will load later

Tags: asp.net-mvc

There are many MVC views in my project which have their own specific JS functions.
I would like to add these functions in the view itself.

```
@{
}
    <div>
    ....
    </div>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#btn").click(function(){
            doSomething();
       });
   });

   function doSomething(){
   }
</script>
```

But the problem is, jQuery reference is at the end of the `body` tag and that cannot be changed. As the view loads earlier, there is an error that $ is undefined.

Is there any way that I can still have the JS inside the view.

Comment: Is your jquery imported in the layout file or in each view? If it is in a layout file, you can use `RenderSection` if it is in the same view, just put local code after jquery is imported.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal jQuery is in the layout. That's why cant change. Could you pls give an example in this context for loading JS using RenderSection. I'm new to MVC. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`RenderSection` is like a placeholder for the HTML. It guarantees that whatever HTML you write will always render in that particular location where it is defined in the layout.

You can use `RenderSection` in your layout as shown below:

```
<body>
...
...
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Then in your views where you are using this layout, you can add `@section` as below:

```
@{
    Layout="_layout.cshtml"
}
<div>
...
...
</div>
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#btn").click(function(){
                doSomething();
           });
        });

        function doSomething(){
        }
    </script>
}
```

For more information, please check [Sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-3.1#sections)